# How to initialize a 3D array which is of type myStruct in Swift?

Tags: c++, arrays, swift, struct

After some heavy searching, I finally found a very intuitive way of initializing a 3D array in Swift:

```
var firstArray = [Int](count:4, repeatedValue: 0)
var secondArray = [[Int]](count:4, repeatedValue: firstArray)
var thirdArray = [[[Int]]](count:4, repeatedValue: secondArray)
```

It works great. I can access any value of the thirdArray:

```
thirdArray[a][b][c]
```

, just like in C++.

But what if I have a struct like:

```
struct myStruct
{
    var color: UIColor = UIColor.redColor()
    var number: Int = 0
    var used: Bool = true
}
```

How do I use now **repeatedValue**?

```
var firstArray = [myStruct](count:4, repeatedValue: ???)
```

Comment: use upper case for your entities `MyStruct`; )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use:

```
var newArray = [myStruct](count:4, repeatedValue: myStruct())
```

The syntax for creating instances of structs and classes is the same.